# Force signature for couple of methods in class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

Is it possible to force signature for couple of methods in class?

Let's say I have `Interface` MyInterface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public void method(int a);
}
```

And I want to implement `MyInterface` in class `MyInterfaceClass` in a way that each method in `MyInterfaceClass` got the same signature?

```
public class MyInterfaceClass implements MyInterface
{
    public void method_A(int a) { /*something */ }
    public void method_B(int a) { /*something */ }
    public void method_C(int a, int b) { /*something */ } // ERROR cause of signature, won't compile
}
```

I have unknown number of methods in `MyInterfaceClass`.

Comment: So you want to have a class where every method has the same signature as that of a single method in an interface it implements? Sounds like a job for reflection to me...

Comment: If the only difference is the length of the parameters you might consider a varargs parameter.

Comment: You need to have a compile error? sounds to me like you need to play around the "compiler" area.

Comment: @Azar, what's reflection? can you point me to some links?

Comment: To "force" the signature of a method you declare it that way.  In the above code sample the only reason that MyInterfaceClass won't compile is that you didn't define `method(int a)`.  Has nothing to do with `method_C`.

Comment: @HotLicks It seems that not all he wants, though. He wants that single method to enforce its signature on all methods of an implementing class (At least, that's what I got out of it).

Comment: @Azar - He doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me. You have a problem (X), which you think you can solve in a certain way, but that leads to a new problem (Y). There is no way anyone can help you here if you don't tell what you actually want.

Comment: I want to create a class, which its methods follow the next rules: all methods have the same privacy level, have the same return type, have the same parameters, have the same checked exception list. The only thing different between the methods is the name... I can take "no" for an answer

Comment: @hudac That's like asking if you can cut a piece of wood with a screwdriver. If that's your goal (for fun, out of curiosity, or whatever) the answer is indeed: no. However, if your goal is to cut the wood, the answer is: use a different tool. So if you insist on your requirements the answer is: you cannot enforce a class like that. If you have an actual use case there most likely is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what you are after here?  In java, a method's signature is made up of 6 factors:

1. privacy level (public, private, etc...)
2. return type
3. method name (cap sensitive)
4. parameters (type and position, method_a(int a, String b) != method_a(String b, int a) )
5. checked exception list

If you wish to implement the method in an interface, you must match all of these criteria INCLUDING the name.  Further, in a class you may only implement an interface's method ONCE.  If you try to implement a method with the same args, name, privacy level, etc... twice then your class will not compile.  How would the java virtual machine know which method to call if you implemented it twice in the same class?

Why do you want to implement the same method twice in one class?  Maybe you are trying to improve your design but your are asking the wrong question?

Comment: I want to create a class, which its methods follow the rules: they have the same privacy level, same return type, same parameters, same checked exception list. The only thing different between them is the name...

Comment: You can absolutely implement multiple methods with those similarities.  However, if you wish to implement a method no an interface then you must have the same params, exceptions, return type (etc) AND THE SAME NAME as the interface method.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code sample the only reason that MyInterfaceClass won't compile is that you didn't define method(int a). Has nothing to do with method_C.

When you adopt an interface you must implement every method in the interface (unless you're creating an abstract class).